# Ansible multi-play playbook silently ignore plays

Tags: ansible

Hope you can help work out why my playbook isn't completing as expected.

ENVIRONMENT

- OSX El Capitan
- ansible 2.1.0.0

CONFIGURATION

Nothing exciting:

```
[defaults]
roles_path=./roles
host_key_checking = False
ssh_args= -t -t
allow_world_readable_tmpfiles = True
```

PLAYBOOK

I have a reasonably involved setup with a number of plays in one playbook.

The playbook is run against different target systems; the production site and a dev rig. (Please don't suggest I combine them... it's an IoT system and complex enough as it is.)

Here's my somewhat redacted playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - ...

- hosts: xmpp_server
  roles:
    - ...

- hosts: audit_server
  roles:
    - ...

- hosts: elk_server
  roles:
    - ...

- hosts: all
  roles:
    - ...
```

Now, please bear in mind that I have an IoT setup with various redundancies, replication and distribution going on, so although there are other ways of skinning the cat, the above decomposition into multiple plays is *really* neat for my setup and I'd like to keep it.

Also important: I have no `audit_server` or `elk_server` hosts on my dev rig. Those groups are currently empty as I'm working on an orthogonal issue and don't need them consuming limited dev resources. I do have those in production, just not in dev.

EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR

On the production site I expect all the plays to trigger and run.

On the dev rig I expect the first play (`all`) and the `xmpp_server` play to run, the `audit_server` and `elk_server` plays to skip and the last (`all`) play to run after that.

ACTUAL BEHAVIOUR

The production site works exactly as expected. All plays run.

The dev rig completes the `xmpp_server` play as `dev-piA` is a member of the `xmpp_server` group. And then it silently stops. No error, no information, nothing. Just straight to the play recap. Here's the output:

```
...

TASK [xmppserver : include] ****************************************************
included: /Users/al/Studio/Projects/smc/ansible/roles/xmppserver/tasks/./openfire.yml for dev-piA

TASK [xmppserver : Get openfire deb file] **************************************
ok: [dev-piA]

TASK [xmppserver : Install openfire deb file] **********************************
ok: [dev-piA]

TASK [xmppserver : Check if schema has been uploaded previously] ***************
ok: [dev-piA]

TASK [xmppserver : Install openfire schema to postgres db] *********************
skipping: [dev-piA]
    to retry, use: --limit @fel.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
dev-vagrant1               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
dev-piA                    : ok=106  changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
dev-piB                    : ok=77   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
dev-piC                    : ok=77   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
...
```

So, I ran it with `-vvvvv` and got nothing more useful:

...

```
TASK [xmppserver : Install openfire schema to postgres db] *********************
task path: /Users/al/Studio/Projects/smc/ansible/roles/xmppserver/tasks/openfire.yml:14
skipping: [dev-piA] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed", "skipped": true}
    to retry, use: --limit @fel.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
dev-vagrant1               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
dev-piA                    : ok=106  changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
dev-piB                    : ok=77   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
dev-piC                    : ok=77   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
...
```

HELP NEEDED

So, my question is: why does the playbook just stop there? What's going on?!

It doesn't actually explicitly say that there are no more hosts left for the audit_server play; that's my best guess. It just stops as if it hit an EOF.

I'm completely stumped.

Edit: NB: The retry file only contains a reference to the vagrant machine, which is currently off. But if the existence of that is the problem then Ansible's logic is very flawed. I'll check now just in case anyway

Edit: OMFG it actually IS the missing vagrant box, which has nothing to do with a goddamn thing. That's shocking and I'll raise it as an issue with Ansible. But... I'll leave this here in case anyone ever has the same problem and googles it.

Edit: For clarity, the vagrant machine is not in the host lists for any of the plays, except the special 'all' case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible folk got back to me and confirmed that they'd been working on a number of issues in this area for the 2.1.1 release.

I updated to 2.1.1.0 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible aborts execution if every host in the play is unhealthy.
If `dev-vagrant1` is the only member of `audit_server` group, this is the expected behavior (as we see `dev-vagrant1` is marked as `unreachable`).

Nevertheless there should be a line `PLAY [audit_server] ********` just before `to retry, use...`

Comment: The vagrant machine is not a member of the host list for any of the plays, except of course 'all'. So unfortunately this explanation is not applicable for my setup.

Comment: But you're right to point out that there should be an informative line about the ignored plays regardless. That's what makes it smell like a bug to me.